# Trouble getting JQUERY API data to display on my webpage using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get certain streamers on Twitch.TV to display automatically on my webpage using AJAX in JQuery.  I appended the AJAX to match the number of users chosen.  However, those specific user names do not display. The code spits out the following.....

AllOnlineOffline

•name: undefined, logo: undefined

•name: undefined, logo: undefined

•name: undefined, logo: undefined

•name: undefined, logo: undefined

•name: undefined, logo: undefined

•name: undefined, logo: undefined

•name: undefined, logo: undefined

•name: undefined, logo: undefined

.....Also, I checked the console.  It shows the API is connecting with the matching number of users.  Yet, I can't get the users to display.  It just shows what's above on the webpage.  I need these streamers, ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "R   obotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"], to be displayed instead. Can anyone tell me how to append the data in AJAX so it populates on my webpage?  Here is my code.

```
var $users = $('#users');
var users =    
["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "R   obotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var onlineChannels = [];
var offlineChannels = [];
var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/jsonp';
$.each(users, function(i, users) {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/freecodecamp',
      headers: {
        'Client-ID': 'qubvi0p9dicv87g9a4s7etay32x6504'
      },
      success: function(data) {

        $users.append('<li>name: ' + users.name + ', logo: ' + users.logo    
+ '</li>').append('<br>').html();
        console.log(data);
      }

    }

  )

})

<script>
<div class="text-center">
<img src="http://siliconangle.com/files/2013/04/twitch-tv-logo-    
lightning.jpg">
</div>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="container">
    <table>
  <br>
      <button id="allChannels" class="btn btn-primary">All</button>
      <button id="Online" class="btn btn-primary">Online</button>
      <button id="Offline" class = "btn btn-primary">Offline</button>
      </br>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="search-container">
    <form>
      <input type="text"></input>
    </form>
  </div>
<div class="streamers-container">
  <ul id="users">

  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: `users` is an array of strings and each its member is a string which doesn't have `.name` or `.logo` properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are not passing the right iteration of the user name when looping. Second, you are referencing the returning json object wrong.

Try this:

```
(function () {
var $users = $('#users');
var users =    
["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "R   obotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var onlineChannels = [];
var offlineChannels = [];
var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/jsonp';
for (var i=0; i < users.length; i++) {
  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/users/' + users[i],
      headers: {
        'Client-ID': 'qubvi0p9dicv87g9a4s7etay32x6504'
      },
      success: function(data) {

        $users.append('<li>name: ' + data.display_name + ', logo: ' + data.logo + '</li>').append('<br>').html();
        console.log(data);
      }

    }

  )

}
})();
```

See my working example jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fictus/7xrnL5n7/

Comment: Your code is ok...You can also optimize the function in this way
[link](https://jsfiddle.net/shall_jsfiddle/m4xhwjg1/2/)

Comment: @fictus  I had the 'for loop' in the wrong place on a previous code.  Also, thanks for clarifying this..... $users.append('<li>name: ' + data.display_name + ', logo: ' + data.logo + '</li>').append('<br>').html();
        console.log(data);..... because I also tried using 'display_name' but never entered data.display_name.  So I appreciate that clarification as well.

Comment: @shall thanks for tweeking the code to make it more efficient.  This is what I needed to better understand the format.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bind problem cause you used users for all elements and for each element

```
$.each(users, function(i, users) {
....
}
```

try to change it into

```
$.each(users, function(i, user) {
....
}
```

Comment: thank you.  However, I made the change as you suggested.  I also made this change.....$users.append('<li>name: ' + user.name + ', logo: ' + user.logo + '</li>').append('<br>').html();
        console.log(data);.....and it still shows the same results.  Can you be more specific?